# "Compile" a simple C program inside a different language

Tags: code-golf

Your task is to take the following simple C code and make a program which will interpret this code and produce a correct output, and be able to handle small modifications to the original code. The C code is

```
int x = 4;
int y = 5;
int z;

z = x * y;

if(z>10)
{
    printf("%d is bigger than 10!",z);
}
```

Or as one line of text.

```
int x = 4; int y = 5; int z; z = x * y; if(z>10){ printf("%d is bigger than 10!",z); }
```

The program must satisfy the following conditions:

- x and y can be changed to any integer.
- "is bigger than 10!" must not be printed if z is smaller than 10.
- The value of 10 can be changed to any integer (not including the 10 in the printed text).
- The program must be able to read the c program in as one line of text.
- Adding spaces shouldn't break the program.

The winning solution is the shortest code to satisfy the criteria. Libraries are not allowed.

Comment: What's the objective winning criterion?

Comment: What would be considered a small modification?

Comment: Changing values of x, y and 10, and renaming variables.

Comment: A program in any language that can be given the above program  and interpret it character by character and reproduce the same results in its own language dealing with variable changes and integer changes in any combination in exactly the same way the program would compiled in a C compiler. So in effect a C compiler that only handles multiplication, if statements and printing.

Comment: Sorry my apologies. The winning code is the shortest code to satisfy that criteria.

Comment: Can `x` and `y` become `a` and `b` resp. ? like `int a = 9; int b = 10; ...` ?

Comment: Also , is the `z` only created by multiplication ? is the `z>10` sign always remains `>` ? if yes, then this is a simple task of printing the text when product of 2 integers is greater than something.

Comment: Yes that's correct. The program must accept the line of code above as it's only input though. The challenge is more in efficiently parsing in a way that works if the things mentioned above are changed.

Comment: @tomnomnom my two comments above specifically call out the things that you forgot to mention. Without those things being mentioned, the spec is unclear right now.

Comment: That is not a valid c program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Perl 5, 76 bytes

```pl
$_=<>,s/ //g,s/[=>](-?\d+)/$.*=$1/ge,($./=$1)>$1&&say"$. is bigger than $1!"
```

Input must be in one line. Negative integers are allowed. Tabs may break program (but spaces are fine, even between `-` and the number).

**Ungolfed:**

```
$_ = <>; # read input
# $. = 1; $. is the number of lines read on STDIN, which should be 1.
s/ //g; # remove whitespace from $_
s/[=>](-?\d+)/ $. *= $1 /ge; # get product of all integers after = or >
$. /= $1; # divide away the last integer found (inside the if)
if($. > $1){ 
   say "$. is bigger than $1";
}
```

This simply extracts the integers and does the product/comparison afterwards.

**Example**:

```
$ perl -E '$_=<>,s/ //g,s/[=>](-?\d+)/$.*=$1/ge,($./=$1)>$1&&say"$. is bigger than $1!"'
> int x =4; int y = -  5 ; int f0_23; f0_23 = x* y ; if ( f0_23> -  30){ printf("%d is bigger than 10!",f0_23) ;  }
-20 is bigger than -30!
```

Comment: The spec is not clear right now. `z` can be a product or a sum too.